# Pricing of bq query with destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

Im running bigquery command line query with destination table

like bq query --destination_table with some select statements from src table.

Whether this will be considered as loading data or querying data ?

Because, loading data is free and query data is going to cost.

My intention is to move some data from src to destination with some manipulations on src fields . So bq query with destination looks a perfect fit for this .

Comment: obviously, this is considered as a query!

Comment: @Mngx: it's important you accept answers when they are correct. That's how Stack Overflow works ;-) Also, see here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824767/max-number-of-partitions-that-can-be-created-on-bigquery-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a query, then you are billed for the cost of the query. It doesn't matter whether you have specified a destination table. If you want to avoid the cost of querying, you need to extract the data, perform whatever transformation you want, and then load it again.